# Clash between Java package in standard library versus Maven artefact (Apache Batik)

Tags: java, maven, apache-batik

Trying to use Apache Batik for SVG export in my modular, Maven-based Java project, I'm running into a problem for which I wonder if there is any decent solution at all.

Adding the required Batik dependency to my POM:

```
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
```

gives rise to the following error:

`The package org.w3c.dom is accessible from more than one module: java.xml, [...], xml.apis`

Yes, indeed, both `java.xml` (which is in the standard Java 17 library) and `xml-apis` (which is part of `batik-dom`) contain the offending package `org.w3c.dom`. I cannot do anything about the first, but I can tell Maven to exclude the second:

```
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
            <version>1.16</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```

Now the project compiles, but throws a run-time error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator`

It turns out the missing class `org.w3c.dom.xpath.XPathEvaluator` *is* in the `xml-apis` sub-module of `batik-dom` but *isn't* in the standard Java library module `java.xml`. In fact, the whole subpackage `org.w3c.dom.xpath` is absent from `java.xml`.

I'll admit I'm stumped. The only solution I can see is to wrap up `org.w3c.dom.xpath` myself in a separate module and include that as a local dependency. I'd be very grateful for an alternative (better) solution. After all, doesn't this problem occur for *whoever* wants to use `batik-dom` in a Maven-based project?

Comment: Why don't you exclude only the org.w3c.dom instead of the whole xml-apis?

Comment: @Joan I would love to, but you can't exclude packages in Maven, only sub-artefacts. `org.w3c.dom` is wrapped in `xml-apis`, nothing I can do about it

Answer (score 0):

A continued search coughed up a solution to my particular problem, though I think this type of issue remains problematic in general. I feel that the exclusion mechanism in Maven just isn't fine-grained enough, depending as it does on the choices of the artefact developers on what to include in which (sub)artefact.

In any case, it turns out the disappearance of `org.w3c.dom.xpath` from the standard Java library was noted as a [JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8054197) some time ago, which was then resolved by moving the package to a separate JDK module, `jdk.xml.dom`. By adding

```
    requires transitive jdk.xml.dom;
```

to my `module-info`, the missing package is now part of my build.

Comment: The exclusions mechanism is based on artifacts (groupId, artifactId, version)... if you like to exclude other things it would be necessary to unpack the dependency etc. (Also you can't be sure everything works afterwards etc.) The real issue here is the original package which contains several components which do not belong there (apart from that the xml-apis package is from 2005... why is it even used?)...

Comment: Of course you can create an JIRA issue for Apache Maven Project and may offer a PR to solve this kind of thing... Here: https://selfserve.apache.org/jira-account.html

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your insight and suggestion. I'm not sure I agree with your analysis of "the real issue" though, as it's at least as much due to the fact that the Java library comes with some components (in this case, `java.xml`) that include extraneous packages (`org.w3c.dom`) but then leave out some subpackages (`org.w3c.com.xpath`). It's a similar problem, but not Maven-related (I think). So maybe it is something that the Java juggernaut should address, rather than the Apache one?

Comment: First the artifact is of 2005 which is a problem and more important packaging different deps into a single jar file leads to a number of problems.. you can not overdrive the transitive dependencies and also to those described issues. It's bad practice to shade/ueberjar different dependencies into a single jar...